# CSS Menu hides behind flash in Chrome (SWFObject)

Tags: css, google-chrome, overlay, swfobject

I am trying to get a CSS menu to overlay on top of a flash player using swfobject.
I have tried modifying z-index, changing the position settings (absolute/relative). I tried different wmodes for swfobject param (transparent/opaque). nothing seems to work.

Basically, it is working in Firefox. But not chrome. I have not tested on IE.

I even followed this tutorial as suggested in a different post: http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/placing-html-elements-over-a-flash-movie/
... and the menus failed to display over top of their example.

[Link](http://www.musicvideocommons.com/en/video/agtzfm12Y29tbW9uc3IgCxIMVmlkZW9ncmFwaGVyGLjqAQwLEgVWaWRlbxj6VQw) to my site.

Comment: Both menus are working fine and visible on my chrome.

Comment: thanks for checking. I forgot to mention that the menus disappear while the video is playing. If the video is paused, then they menus display over the paused video just fine.
Also: I am running Chrome on linux. So this may be a specific issue with chrome and flash for linux. I will have to borrow a windows box to check this.

Comment: works fine on my Mac (Chrome)